# Combining pipes and here documents in the shell for SSH

Tags: shell, ssh

Okay, so I've recently discovered the magic of here documents for feeding stdin style lines into interactive commands. However, I'm trying to use this with SSH to execute a bunch of commands on a remote server, but I also need to pipe in some actual input, before executing the extra commands, to confound matters further I also need to get some results back ;)

Here's what I'm trying to use:

```
#!/bin/sh
RESULT=$(find -type f "$PATH" | gzip | ssh "$HOST" <<- 'REMOTE_SYNC'
    cat > "/tmp/.temp_file"

    # Do something with /tmp/.temp_file
REMOTE_SYNC
```

Is this actually correct? Part of the problem I'm having as well is that I need to pipe the data to that file in /tmp, but I should really be generating a randomly named temp file, but I'm not sure how I could do that, assign the name to a variable (so I can get back to it) and still send stdin into it.

I may also extract the find | gzip part to a separate command run locally first, as the gzipped file will likely be small enough that sending it when ready will result in a much shorter SSH connection then sending it as it's generated, but it still doesn't get around the fact that I need to be able to provide both stdin and my extra commands to SSH.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reinvent `rsync`; you might want to use that instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do it like this. Both heredoc and the piped input compete for stdin, and only one wins. Look at this example:

```
echo test | cat << EOF
TEST
EOF
```

What will this print? `test`, `TEST` or both? It prints `TEST`, so the heredoc wins (at least in bash).

You don't really need this anyway. Luckily `ssh` takes a [`command`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/ssh.1.php) argument, which will be passed on to the shell on the remote host, so you can just use your command as a string here. So something like this:

```
echo TEST | ssh user@host 'cat > tempfile; cat tempfile; rm tempfile'
```

would work (althoug it doesn't make much sense), the output of the left side commands is piped through `ssh` to the remote host and supplied as stdin there.

If you want the data to be compressed when sending it through ssh, you can just enable compression using the `-C` option.

---

edit:

Using linebreaks inside a string is perfectly fine, so this works fine too:

```
echo TEST | ssh user@host '
    cat > tempfile
    cat tempfile
    rm tempfile
'
```

The only difference to a heredoc would be that you have to escape quotes.

If you use something like `echo TEST | ssh user@host "$(<script.sh)"` you can write everything into a file...

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to still use a here document rather than trying to condense my commands into that string argument; I may have to try sending the data and commands as a single stream via stdin, so I only have to add commands for breaking them apart and running the shell script. Thanks though!

Comment: added some more examples. I don't think sending commands and input on the same input stream isn't a good idea...